# animation scrolling effect with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want same effect but side panel which showing A B C D like to stick on same just side content will scroll down or up on click of any
A B C D - currently whole content going up

```js
$('.sidebar li').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-atr');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 left-sidebar-content">
    <ul class="sidebar">
      <li id="li_1" data-atr="A" class="Active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">A</a></li>
      <li id="li_2" data-atr="B"><a href="javascript:void(0)">B</a></li>
      <li id="li_3" data-atr="C"><a href="javascript:void(0)">C</a></li>
      <li id="li_4" data-atr="D"><a href="javascript:void(0)">D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="" id="A">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for A</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="B">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for B</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="C">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for C</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="D">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for D</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container  -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a bit of css change:

```
    .sidebar{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    .tab-content{
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
```

```js
$('.sidebar li').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-atr');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style> 
        .sidebar{
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }
        .tab-content{
            margin-left: 100px;
        }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 left-sidebar-content">
    <ul class="sidebar">
      <li id="li_1" data-atr="A" class="Active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">A</a></li>
      <li id="li_2" data-atr="B"><a href="javascript:void(0)">B</a></li>
      <li id="li_3" data-atr="C"><a href="javascript:void(0)">C</a></li>
      <li id="li_4" data-atr="D"><a href="javascript:void(0)">D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="" id="A">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for A</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="B">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for B</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="C">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for C</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="D">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for D</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container  -->
```

Comment: Actually Kris J was first with the same suggestion.

Comment: That is true, however I haven't copied his answer. OP feel free to move the accepted answer to Kris J.

Comment: I know you haven't. The comment was to OP so he could give some rep to a low rep guy to bring him above 50 rep

Comment: Actually the solution is less elegant as the links are overlapping with the content, and OP needs to copy out the codes and try to place it in hos code. In a way, I think it is fair to have this answer as accepted.
+1 to Kris J. for the speed.

Comment: Right. I did not see the overlap on my screen

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/kcmyxqkf/1/

Just give your css this:

```
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.col-lg-8{
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```js
$('.sidebar li').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-atr');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.col-lg-8 {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 left-sidebar-content">
    <ul class="sidebar">
      <li id="li_1" data-atr="A" class="Active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">A</a></li>
      <li id="li_2" data-atr="B"><a href="javascript:void(0)">B</a></li>
      <li id="li_3" data-atr="C"><a href="javascript:void(0)">C</a></li>
      <li id="li_4" data-atr="D"><a href="javascript:void(0)">D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="" id="A">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for A</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="B">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for B</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="C">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for C</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>
      <div class="" id="D">
        <h3 class="section-title">Content for D</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
          egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
          Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container  -->
```

Comment: @mplungjan which container? Works fine on safari.

Comment: It works only if the `.container` is the size of ONE div. On my screen clicking does nothing since the div is fully visible.

Comment: Had you made a snippet here, it would have seemed to work better, like the accepted answer does.

Comment: Yeah thats true my window was smaller. Will do it right next time thanks.

Comment: When it is, it overlays the content

Comment: @mplungjan yeah you would have to give it more room on top

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want ABCD to stick on the left? This can be achieved easily with CSS `position: fixed`. See [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcmyxqkf/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Css of just one line will solve the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sidebar li').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-atr');

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      });
    });
```

```css
.left-sidebar-content .sidebar {position: fixed; top: 40px; left: 10px; }
.tab-content{margin-left: 80px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 left-sidebar-content">
        <ul class="sidebar">
          <li id="li_1" data-atr="A" class="Active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">A</a></li>
          <li id="li_2" data-atr="B"><a href="javascript:void(0)">B</a></li>
          <li id="li_3" data-atr="C"><a href="javascript:void(0)">C</a></li>
          <li id="li_4" data-atr="D"><a href="javascript:void(0)">D</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="" id="A">
            <h3 class="section-title">Content for A</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
              egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
              Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
          </div>
          <div class="" id="B">
            <h3 class="section-title">Content for B</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
              egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
              Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
          </div>
          <div class="" id="C">
            <h3 class="section-title">Content for C</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
              egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
              Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
          </div>
          <div class="" id="D">
            <h3 class="section-title">Content for D</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus, massa mattis tincidunt lacinia, orci elit placerat justo, nec iaculis justo diam ut magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
              egestas. In lacinia quam tellus, sed feugiat nisl viverra non. Phasellus ut blandit turpis. Aliquam et nisl ut ex varius porta. Sed rhoncus pretium libero, sit amet volutpat libero elementum eu. Suspendisse imperdiet pulvinar ipsum non lacinia.
              Aenean pulvinar sit amet sapien id iaculis. Donec sit amet mi malesuada, congue nisi id, tristique tellus</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```